# cash2advance3 hidden link in HTML

Tags: wordpress, malware

I was looking over the source code for a website I will be developing when I noticed a strange link pointing to cash2advance3.com which is based in Florida.

```
<div class=ldn5>same day <a href=http://cash2advance3.com/ >cash advance</a></div> </p>
```

I did some googling and found that this link is on many wordpress sites. I am wondering if there is an easy way to view a which theme the site is using or if I should push the cash2advance3 company for more information regarding this.

Here are some examples of websites with the link:

- http://alagen.com/
- http://littlepepperpromotions.com/

Comment: That's link spam inserted through a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same link on a wordpress site I help out with.  Malicious code had been injected into the top of the "functions.php" file for the theme the site was using (Anthology).  I suspect it was injected before we updated to the current version of Wordpress, so I'm hoping whatever vulnerability was leveraged to do that has been mitigated by now.  Still changing all the passwords though...